# Python - sum of multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000

Tags: python, python-3.x

The problem sounds like this:
"If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.

Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000."

I have written some code below and I'm confused as to why it doesn't work

```
s1 = 0
s2 = 0
for i in range(0,1000,3):
    s1 = s1 + i
for i in range(0,1000,5):
    s2 = s2 + i
suma = s1 + s2
print(suma)
```

On top of this, I tried assigning the value of 0 to all the variables at once:

```
suma, s1, s2 = 0
#the rest of the code here
```

And I'm getting the following error:
**TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object**

How do I assign everything at once? Do I even need to assign every variable to 0 in order for my code to work or is it similar to Turbo Pascal where every int variable automatically gets assigned 0?

Comment: `s1, s2 = 0, 0`

Comment: You will count 15, 30, 45, etc. twice the way you are doing it.

Comment: I'm not sure what people downvote this. You showed your work, formatted the question well, and had a reproducible problem. +1.

Comment: @theX you can also do multiple assignment in one line as follows: `suma = s1 = s2 = 0`

Comment: Maybe it was downvoted because it is unclear, not useful, or shows no research effort.

Comment: I think you've forgotten what it was like to be a beginner @mkrieger1. The existing code might represent a fair amount of work. It's pretty unfair to say it shows no research effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Pythonic as @MarkMeyer's answer may be, let's fix your original code to produce the correct result.  (And assign the value 0 to all the variables at once.)

```
s1 = s2 = s3 = 0

for i in range(0, 1000, 3):
    s1 += i

for i in range(0, 1000, 5):
    s2 += i

for i in range(0, 1000, 3 * 5):
    s3 += i

suma = (s1 + s2) - s3

print(suma)
```

Comment: Thank you for grabbing my initial code and fixing it! I was a tad bit confused by Mark's code, but this clears it up. Also thank you for showing me the += operator, this will really clean everything up and I won't have to use ancient methods such as s1=s1+i anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Counting each range one at a time counts the numbers that are multiples of *both* 5 and 3, like 15 and 30, twice.

A more python way to do this would be to imagine taking the range as a sequence and filtering out all numbers that don't meet your criteria. Then sum up the sequence. For multiples of 5 or 3 (or both), that criteria might look like:

```
n % 3 == 0 or n % 5 == 0
```

`%` produces the remainder divided by the following number. For any `n` this is only true if it is a multiple of 5 or 3. You can use that to filter the range and sum:

```
sum(n for n in range(10) if n % 3 == 0 or n % 5 == 0)
# 23
```

This works because the inner bit makes an iterator of just the values you want:

```
[n for n in range(10) if n % 3 == 0 or n % 5 == 0]
# [0, 3, 5, 6, 9]
```

And summing that with the builtin function [sum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) gives the correct answer.

Also the error you are getting is because this format of assignment tries to unpack several values:

```
a, b, c = [1, 2, 3] # works
a, b, c = 10 # error -- not enough values.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def get_multiples(num):
    if num%3==0 or num%5==0:
        return num

n=int(input("Enter a number = "))
multiples = sum(set(list(filter(get_multiples, list(range(n))))))
print(multiples)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**